# using one time data base access while writing unix shell script using functions and sql queries

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, ksh

I have developed a script which would delete the records from a table (with millions of records ) based on a specific criteria. Below is the script. But my requirement is to use one instance of calling the data base access. In this script I have used the access twice. I don't know how can I write this with one time data base access which would do the required deletion and selection;

```
#!/bin/ksh
#set -u
log()
{

   local date='date +"%b %d %Y  %T"'
   echo "$date [log]       : $*." | tee -a $logfile

}


declaration()

{
   date='date +"%b_%d_%Y_%T"'
   LOGPATH=/opt/RP/abcd/
   logfile=$LOGPATH"record_"$date

}


checkstatus ()

{
COUNT=`sqlplus -s $ORACLE_USR <<END // using the database access for the first time
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
SELECT  count(*) FROM name WHERE age  not in('12,'24,'38','50') AND trunc(dstamp)=trunc(sysdate-10) ;
exit;
END`

log "$COUNT records found "
}

deleterecord ()
{
sqlplus -s $ORACLE_USR  <<END  // using the database access for the second time
DELETE from name WHERE age  not in('12,'24,'38','50') AND trunc(dstamp)=trunc(sysdate-10) 
AND Rownum <=30000;
COMMIT;
EXIT;
END
}

declaration
checkstatus

while [ $COUNT -gt 0 ]
do
deleterecord
COUNT=$(( $COUNT - 30000 ))
if [ $COUNT -lt 0 ]
then
log "All records are deleted"
else
log "$COUNT records remaining in table"
fi
done
```

Comment: Please tag appropriately. You are using Oracle, not MySQL. Why the requirement to access the DB only once? Sounds artificial, or maybe like a class assignment?

Comment: I have corrected the tag. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: I need to call the data base only once in the script. But the deletion should happen in loop as well...

Comment: so put it all in an anonymous pl/sql block

Comment: You are using database access not oly twice, but once for the rowcount and then once for every chunck of 30.000 rows. As long as you are doing the loop in the shell, you can't avoid accessing the database multiple times. Either you move the loop into your sql (I am not familiar with pl/sql, but a google on 'plsql loop' should give you pointers), or you create a script with the approprate number of delete statements and run that with sqlplus.